# Error when using remote api with google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Google app engine SDK installed to: `/usr/local/google_appengine`

Here is my script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf8
import os, sys
p = '/usr/local/google_appengine'
if p not in sys.path:
  sys.path.append(p)

import dev_appserver
dev_appserver.fix_sys_path()

GAE_USER = '*hide*'
GAE_PASS = '*hide*'

from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.api import search, memcache


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mkiniGAE.py", line 15, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
ImportError: No module named appengine.ext.remote_api
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this line to make it work:

```
if 'google' in sys.modules:
    del sys.modules['google']
```

Also needed to add 'fancy_urlib' to path:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(p, 'lib', 'fancy_urllib'))
```

So the final code should look something like:

```
import os, sys
GAE_PATH = '/usr/local/google_appengine'

if 'google' in sys.modules:
    del sys.modules['google']

EXTRA_PATHS = [
    GAE_PATH,
    os.path.join(GAE_PATH, 'lib', 'fancy_urllib'),
]

if 'google' in sys.modules:
    del sys.modules['google']

for path in EXTRA_PATHS:
    sys.path.append(path)

from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
```